# Extract all the parameters from MySQLCommand including FROM clause

Tags: mysql, .net

I use MySql librairy in .NET. Is there any way to get the table used in a MySQLCommand other than using string manipulations considering the query.
Let say my query is "SELECT FOO_FIELD FROM FOO_TABLE" and i'd like to get the table used in the query (FOO_TABLE), how do i do that?

I've looked for an answer in the Mysql documentation but can't find anything https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/Properties_T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand.htm

Comment: You mean some method or properties from the MySqlCommand class?

Comment: Exactly...Some dedicated way instead of using some regex or string manipulation with the string storing the sql query...

Comment: I don't think you could find anything in this context out of the box- MySqlCommand implements the IDbCommand interface specification as decided by the ADO.NET developers and there is nothing for that. Unless MySql adds something particular to this class there is no way to extract info from an internal parser (that probably doesn't even exist).